# What is the best way to markup a testimonial in XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, markup, semantic-markup, quotations

I used to just use `p` and `span` elements for this... but I'm always pushing to use the *right* elements, and this is something I haven't really thought about before with regard to testimonials.

This is what I had in mind...

```
<div class="testimonial">
 <blockquote>I love your products!</blockquote>
 <span>Jim Testimonial-giver</span>
</div>
```

Does that look like the best way to do this? Is there a best practice?

I looked at how the [W3C markup testimonials](http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xhtml-m12n-testimonial) on their site, and they have used...

```
<blockquote>
 <p>
  <a id="aptest" name="aptest">Applied Testin.....</a>
  <br />
  <span class="QuoteAttr">-- Shane P. M...</span>
 </p>
</blockquote>
```

Should I just copy how the W3C did it, after all *shouldn't they be correct*?

Comment: IMHO, your way is simpler and cleaner. keep it like that.

Comment: Someone at W3C needs to do some refactoring...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [cite tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1):

```
<div class="testimonial">
 <blockquote>i love your products</blockquote>
 <cite>Jim Testimonial-giver</cite>
</div>
```

Also I would probably do it like this:

```
<blockquote class="testimonial">
  i love your products
  <cite>Jim Testimonial-giver</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Just to make it slightly more semantic and clearly tie the citation with the quote. Divs should only be necessary for structural things.

Comment: Thanks Rex ... I can't believe I forgot the cite element!

Comment: Do you think if there's a bunch of them, they should go in an unordered list?

Comment: @alex I do love unordered lists :) I am leaning towards yes myself, but I wouldn't frown at not using them in this particular case.

Comment: The `cite` element should *not* be a child of the `blockquote` element, as its content (= the author name) is not part of the "[quoted text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2)".

Answer (score 4):

The [Mozilla.org style guide](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/contribute/writing/markup.html) seems to prefer using `q` for the quotation and `<cite>` for the author, wrapped in a `<blockquote>` or a `<div>` with an appropriate class. [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) seems to strongly frown on using `<cite>` for people's names; it says that it should only be used for the titles of works.

Following that model, perhaps something like this:

```
<blockquote class="testimonial">
  <q>I love your products!</q>
  <cite>Jim Testimonial-giver</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Or if you don't want to use `<cite>`, then:

```
<blockquote class="testimonial">
  <q>I love your products!</q>
  <span class="quote-attribution">Jim Testimonial-giver</span>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: It's a bit of a quibble, but I'm going to disagree here - the q element is not supported in IE, and since there's no need to distinguish between the contents of the q and any other element (it's the only - and primary - block of text in blockquote), it seems superfluous.

Comment: The q element is supported in IE 8. It depends on whether you want to insert the quotes or not, and whether you want them to display in earlier versions of IE. The nice thing about the q element is that you can get properly nested smart quotes if you set your your :before and :after selectors.

Comment: +1 for citing (hah) an excellent resource I was looking for (Mozilla style guide), even though the link is broken :(

Comment: @steve Fixed the link to an archive of what was there.

Comment: Here someone is quoting (`blockquote`) someone who quoted (`q`) something.

Answer (score 1):

For a long time I used [Tantek Çelik's slide](http://tantek.com/presentations/2005/09/elements-of-xhtml/#slide13) as a reference when it came to quotations.

But seeing the comments by alex and Rex M, I'm thinking about this implementation for testimonials:

```
<ul id="testimonials">
  <li>
    <blockquote>
      i love your products
    </blockquote>
    <cite>&mdash;Jim Testimonial-giver</cite>
  </li>
  <li>
    <blockquote>
      i love your products even more
    </blockquote>
    <cite>&mdash;Joe Testimonial-giver</cite>
  </li>
  [...]
</ul>
```